# Delphi XE3 Ctrl+Z undo caret movements too

Tags: delphi, configuration

I'm new to Delphi and I've found some strange behaviors of Rad Studio XE3 code editor.

E.g., when i press the undo shortcut (`Ctrl+Z`), the editor does not undo just the last code editing, but also latest caret movements. I mean: when I open a unit and I browse through its code, it happens that I go clicking around, without editing the code. Well, if I press Ctrl+Z, the caret will move back to all points where I've been clicking before. I was expecting nothing to happen when I press `Ctrl+Z`, if no edit was performed!

There is a way to deactivate this feature?

I've `CnWizards_1.0.0.638` installed.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean cursor? Or do you mean caret? The cursor is the mouse pointer. The caret is the text insert point in an edit control.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, I meant the caret. I'll update the question. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder how a developer could eventually think that the caret position is a nice to have in the Undo/Redo history.

Comment: Only Delphi does this. Insane functionality. If you undo a bunch of stuff and accidentally (or intentionally) click in the code editor - which repositions the cursor - you lose the redo buffer - say goodbye to your changes. On a side note, I recently set up Delphi from scratch and started coding, and found that Undo after Save was off by default, which really should not be (legacy memory usage considerations probably).

Comment: Now on Delphi 12, undo/redo is rubbish as always. Corrupt characters pop up (and IDE locks up) occasionally, if you undo/redo often. Delphi 11's undo/redo was particularly bad, I think Delphi 12 is slightly better, but still bad. Sometimes during undo/redo, caret ends up in the beginning of the file and no more redo. It's easy to reproduce too, happens constantly. Clean install - no plugins. If you undo, Alt+Tab to another window, redo is gone. I guess unless things are reported, it's never gonna get fixed huh. I think Emba is doomed. This fiasco with servers being down, I think I've had it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot disable that behavior completely, but you can reduce its effect. Turn on the [*group undo* editor option](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Editor_Options). Then all consecutive cursor movements will be grouped into a single action. Other types of consecutive actions will be grouped together, too, but I don't recall that being an issue for me.

Comment: Thanks, but "group undo" checkbox was already enabled. When disabled, I notice that I must press Ctrl+Z twice to make the caret move to previous positions.

Comment: I had to turn off Group Undo because sometimes Delphi bundles too much into 1 operation so when you undo/redo, you can't see clearly what was changed. To have a quick moan: in Delphi 11.1, I found my redo lost after doing an undo, constantly - something (who knows what) caused the editor to reset its redo buffer. Flakiness in this functionality is scary as one develops mistrust in the undo/redo functionality. In VS, I could undo hundreds (if not thousands) of changes, and safely redo everything to where I was. Delphi would fall over in such extreme scenarios.

Comment: The "Group undo" checkbox undoes all the caret movements if I use arrow keys to move it, as expected - but if I use mouse click to move the caret then I must press Ctrl+Z twice(!!!) to undo each caret movement. (in RAD Studio 10.4.2)

Answer (score 1):

Moving the caret when performing undo of edit actions is very much by design. This is for sure not strange behaviour and all editors behave this way.

If the caret was not moved, and the window now scrolled, you would have absolutely no feedback that an undo event had occurred. For instance, the edit that you undo could perhaps be in code that is not currently visible. For sure in plain Delphi there is no way to change the behaviour and I'd be astounded if any plugin offered such functionality because it would render the undo functionality completely unusable.

Perhaps what you want to do is to undo some changes, and then return to where you were in the edit window before performing the undo operations. Well, the way to achieve that is to drop a bookmark, perform the undo, and then jump to the bookmark.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not very clear and I was not able to explain my point. I've updated it!

Comment: Well, that's a different question now.

Comment: Old thread but wanted to comment as was looking for an answer to somehow change this functionality. Visual Studio (2019) IDE doesn't treat cursor movements as buffer changes - you can click around without 'adding' to the undo nor resetting the redo. After using VS for a few years, I found it refreshing - the stupid Delphi Editor behaviour that bothered me for years (and caused me losing redo buffer on many occasions) was not there. Most editors actually don't do what Delphi does. AkelPad and Notepad++ to name a couple.

Comment: I had to downvote this answer.
I agree with TByte. Bufferring caret movements is not normal behavior, and quite irritating in my opinion. Even with the "Group undo" option enabled the behavior is quite inconsistent. For example if I move the caret with arrow keys, then group undo will work, however if I make the same caret movements using mouse click then group undo fails, and I even have to use 'Undo' x2 times to undo each individual mouse click.
NP++, VScode, VS, any form in any browser, word, excel, to name a few, all do not count cursor movement as 'changes' to be undone, by default.

Comment: @PhilB just tried npp and it does not do what you say

Comment: Hey @DavidHeffernan thanks for the reply!

I rechecked - and I really don't think npp treats caret movement, via click or keyboard, as 'changes' to be undone - using the latest version of npp. I couldn't find a setting which'd affect that behavior either. Only actual 'changes' i.e. something which put the file into an 'unsaved changes' state, are considered when using the Undo/Redo actions.

I'm kind of surprised that anyone thinks way RAD Studio does it is at all intuitive, or mainstream.

Comment: Reading your answer again, I think we have our wires crossed a bit.

I don't think anyone is suggesting that caret should not move when using undo. It should move to position where the text has been added or removed.

The complaint is that the caret movement itself is not a change - pressing ctrl+Z shouldn't be undoing caret movements, it should undo changes. Moving the caret in the editor, with a mouse click, or keyboard arrows, is not a file change. In RADStudio, moving the caret, without file changes, is still counted as a 'change' for the undo action. No other editor does that AFAIK.

Comment: With group undo on, undo/redo often groups too much, so massive chunks of code suddenly appear/disappear. Without group undo, there's less unpredictability, but it's broken the last time I tried it (try it and see - you'll be holding CTRL+Z/CTRL+SHIFT+Z for many seconds at a time because there's some tiny bits added to the buffer that we don't see. The functionality is so bad as if it's written by a novice. So many tools and editors have near-rock solid undo/redo these days, even friggin' MS Word got there with an undo/redo you can trust. It's clearly not a trivial area....

Comment: ...in my experience, many tools mess this up, but these days I am seeing very reliable undo/redo and dread it less when I do deep ones. But Delphi being so poor at it boggles my mind and frustrates me a great deal. Every day it screws up. Every release, I hope someone fixed it. Jump lists (Alt+Left/Right) are glitchy and unpredictable too - often doesn't take you back where you were. As if it depends on whether you clicked/moved around enough in an area or not. In VS, I can have external programs write to the file I'm editing and I can undo/redo those changes. VS is *ridiculously* good at this

Comment: In Delphi, if you made a change, then inspected code for a while, browsed around, clicked around, say you did that hundreds of times, and you want to get back to the original change, you have to sit and wait for the caret jumping all over the place until you reach the actual changes, and you better release CTRL+Z on time, or you'll go too far :) Delphi doesn't always position the caret either when undoing a change - you don't always notice there was a change (typical with group undo turned on)....

Comment: It's just how they did it originally and it hasn't changed/been improved since. I bet that area hasn't been touched at all for over 25 years. I see the same editor corrupting buffer bug or lost redos because I breathed on the IDE. They have bigger fish to fry I suppose, like skinning the IDE and buying buggy third-party extensions (Parnassus Bookmarks f.i.). How is this not on top of the list, I don't know. Embarcadero doesn't take this seriously and I think they've made all the bad impression on me they could over the years. I have no hope for this company, they'll go bust the way it's going.